# multivariable limit question

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Is this an acceptable solution?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\sin(2(x^2+y^2))}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$t=x^2+y^2$$
So $t\rightarrow0$. Now I change the limit to:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(2t)}{t}=2$$
This solution makes sense to me, but I am still having doubts.

Comment: Looks just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine. In fact, it's very similar to the common technique of switching to polar coordinates. In that technique, one puts $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ and evaluates the limit as $r \to 0$. This is equivalent to putting $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. You've put $r = x^2 + y^2$ instead. Check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316806/4583) for more information on this technique and others.

Answer (score 0):

Or, indeed, the technique used for evaluating $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{x}.$$
Any time $u\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, it is easy to check with the official limit definition that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(u(x)) = \lim_{u\to 0} f(u)\,.$$
The same applies when $x$ is a vector.