# When can L'Hospital rule be used on Multivariable limits.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am wondering about a multivariable limit, and in particular, is it ever valid to use L'hospital rule.

For example, I am working on $$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,1)} \frac{x^3-y}{x-y}$$

This is what I have done,

let $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3-y}{x-y}$$

$f(x,0) \rightarrow 1$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)$

and similiary

$f(0,y) \rightarrow 1$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)$

Okay now here is where I have a few questions ( I haven't looked at the answer or used wolfram or anything because I want to make sure I understand it first), should I continue to try out different parts, or should I try to see if I can prove the limit is 1.

in trying different paths, say $$f(x,x^2)=\frac{x^2(1-x^3)}{(1-x)}$$ would it now be valid to use L'hospital? because the y is gone and we would have 0/0 as x $\rightarrow 1$? or is it never valid to use this rule for multi valued?

Is this the right approach I should be taking or is there something else I should be thinking of?

Thank you

Comment: That approach is fine. In this case, you don't need L'Hopital, since $\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}=1+x+x^2$ when $x\neq 1$. But your formula for $f(x,x^2)$ seems wrong.

Comment: You won't dare using L'Hospital's rule for a quotient of *polynomials*? That's using a sledgehammer to crash a nut.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews , I see, and Im just wondering , you can only approach upon paths that are in the domain correct?

Comment: The answers have addressed a few relevant points.

I'll be addressing other problems.

A sublimit is a limit of a restriction of a function. Something like "$f(x,0) \rightarrow 1$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)$" would be another way of writing $$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (1,1)}g(x,y)=1,$$ where $g$ is $f$ restricted to $\{(x,0)\colon x\in \mathbb R\}\cap \text{dom}(f)$. But limits can only be taken at points belonging to the closure of the domain of a function and $(1,1)$ isn't in the closure of the domain of $g$. What you wrote has no meaning.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks, but what part has no meaning, taking the limit of f(x,x^2)?

Comment: @LearningMath The part I quoted: "$f(x,0) \rightarrow 1$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (1,1)$". Intuitively the second coordinate is $0$, it can't approach $1$. The one you mention in your last comment is OK.

Comment: Sooooo how would you solve this limit, then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bear in mind the L'Hospital's rule goes for **single**-variable limits, only. Checking a lot of different paths will not guarantee the existence of the limit. But if you find **any** two different paths which give you different numbers, then the limit does not exists.

That being said, once you have chosen a path, the limit becomes a single-variable on, so **yes**, you can use L'Hospital. For example:

> in trying different paths, say $f(x,x^2)=\frac{x^2(1−x^3)}{(1−x)}$ would it now
>   be valid to use L'hospital? because the $y$ is gone and we would have
>   $0/0$ as $x →1$?

Here you chose a path, and now you have a single-variable limit. You can use L'Hospital.

---

**Edit:** It seems that there is a sort of L'Hospital's rule for multi-variable limits, as pointed by Git Gud in the comments. [Check it out](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0363.pdf).

Comment: Of course, checking a lot of paths to find a counter-example *will* be useful, however. :)

Comment: in which case we would have 5, implies the limit does not exist than?

Comment: I don't know, haven't done the calculations. Give me 2 seconds.

Comment: I got $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x,x^2)=3$, but ok, the limit won't exist anyway.

Comment: Yes I meant 3 ,

Answer (score 0):

There will be some cases where L'Hopital's rule naively applied will give the right answer for a double limit.  But to understand when you are in such a case would require a deeper knowledge of the function, so l'Hopital's rule is pretty useless for proving the limit exists (although it is still useful to prove tha a limit does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=1+t, y=1+t^{\alpha}$. Then
$$f(x,y)=\frac{t^3+3t^2+3t-t^{\alpha}}{t-t^{\alpha}}\sim_0\begin{cases}\dfrac{3t}t=3&\text{if}\enspace \alpha>1,\\\dfrac{-t^{\alpha}}{t^{\alpha}}=-1&\text{if}\enspace 0<\alpha<1\end{cases}.$$
Hence the limit is $3$ if $\alpha>1$, $-1$ if $0<\alpha<1$. This proves there is no limit at $(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, but where would the intuition for this come from? Does it always work?

Comment: @LearningMath [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316806/is-there-a-step-by-step-checklist-to-check-if-a-multivariable-limit-exists-and-f) question might interest you. There's no recipe for finding multivariate limits, you practice enough and think about the examples enough to get a feeling of what happens. On another note, as useful as this answer is to solving the problem, I don't think it answers any of your questions, so perhaps you might want to adjust your question to encompass Bernard's answer as a possible answer.

Comment: The most common way to find a limit  (if there is one) or prove there isn't, is to use polar coordinates and try to factor the function as the polar radius times a bounded expression. If you  can't do it, you may suspect there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKtnw.png)L.Hopital rule is used in the case of indeterminate forms. the present example is suitable for existence limits at $(1,1)$ but not equal.
This way, limit does not exist is the conclusion. 
Therefore, this example is not suitable for L.Hopital rule for multivariate function.