# Can a function be inexistent at the origin but still be continuous there?

Tags: continuity

I have:
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{equation}

Is this function continuous at the origin, still it does not exist there?

Thanks

Comment: In polar coordinates the function is $r\cos\theta\sin\theta$, which _does_ have the value $0$ at the origin (or if you want to be pedantic, the singularity is removable).

Comment: This requires a transformation. If f is to be defined for continuity on R, should transformations be included from Cartesian systems?

Comment: You would transform the origin too to radial coordinates.

Comment: Your computations don't make much sense. Just from looking along the axes (is that what you're doing? – it's not clear what you mean by “$(x,y) \to (0,x)$”, for example), you can't conclude that the multivariable limit exists. And your “multivariable l'Hospital's rule” is also wrong; the expression “$f'(x,y)/g'(x,y)$” is meaningless!

Comment: @Hans Lundmark https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203220/when-can-lhospital-rule-be-used-on-multivariable-limits

Comment: @vqngs: Yes? What do you want to say with that?

Answer (score 4):

Functions can only be continuous at points in their domain. $(0,0)$ is not in the domain of $f_1$, so speaking of continuity at $(0,0)$ is nonsensical.

---

Note that, as others have pointed out, there exists an *extension* of $f_1$ which is in fact continuous at the origin. That function is

$$F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$$
$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}f_1(x,y); & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0;&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}.$$

The function $F$ is equal to $f_1$ on the entire domain of $f_1$, but the function $F$ also contains $0$ in its domain, and it is continous at $0$.

---

Note also that $F$ is the **only** function on $\mathbb R^2$ that both extends $f_1$ (i.e., returns the same value as $f_1$ on all points in the domain of $f_1$) **and** is continuous.

Comment: Which theorem states this?

Comment: @vqngs The definition of continuity.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will look this theorem up.

Comment: @vqngs It is not a theorem, it is a definition.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But what about @Parcly Taxel
comment?

Comment: The limit can exist as you approach a point outside the domain of definition. That means you can *extend* the domain but it does not automatically make that point a part of the domain.

Comment: That comment says that you can extend the domain so that the function is defined at the origin. And that you can do it in such a way that the new function is continuous at the origin.

Comment: To be clear: you can create a new function that agrees with the old function at all points in the domain of the old function. The new function, though, could have a strictly larger domain (such as including the origin in the OP), and the new function can be continuous there because it’s part of the domain.

Comment: The domain is R, R includes the origin, but at origin f does not exist. But a limit exist as  R approaches the origin, so this is discontinuity of the first kind, since there is an asymptote at 0,0

Comment: No. If the function doesn't exist / doesn't have a value / isn't defined at a point, then that point is not in the domain of the function. That's what "domain" means.

Comment: @5xum, the definition of continuity is that , for two metric spaces, X and Y, and f maps E into Y, where E subset of Y at p, for every epsilon>0, then there exists a delta>0 such that:  d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon . So at p=0, d_Y(f(x,y), f(0,0))<\epsilon , but since f(0,0) does not exist, then d_Y((f(x,y), f(0,0)) does not exists, and there is no epsilon that can quantify continuity. You are right.

Comment: @vqngs Exactly. But, as others have pointed out, there exists an *extension* of $f_1$ which is in fact continuous at the origin. That function is

$$F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$$
$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}f_1(x,y); & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0;&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

Comment: @vqngs More fundamentally, note on your definition that $p$ is explicitly specified to be in the domain of $f$.

Comment: @vqngs The function $F$ is equal to $f_1$ on the entire domain of $f_1$, but the function $F$ also contains $0$ in its domain, and it is continous at $0$.

Comment: @5xum thanks.  cannot change that definition anymore, it is locked Arthur.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, the proper question is "Can $f$ be extended to $(0,0)$ as a continuous function?". The answer is yes because, since $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)= 0$, defining $f(0,0)=0$ automatically yields a continuous function.

You can see this simply by noting that
$$
\left| \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0 \right|\leq \dfrac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0.
$$

I used the inequalities
$$ |x| = \sqrt{x^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$ |y| = \sqrt{y^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$