# Limit of function as it approaches origin

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative, limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit of $f$ or prove that limit does not exist as $(x,y)$ approaches origin point.

$$f(x,y) = \frac{2x}{x^2 + x+ y^2}$$

So far, I have used several methods, such as finding correct $2$ paths for nonexistence of limit or applying polar coordinates, but I could not solve it properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean you could not solve it "properly"? What "wrong" answers did you get?

Comment: Try for $t>0$ $ x=-t$, and  $y=\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a step by step checklist to check if a multivariable limit exists and find its value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316806)

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x,x)=\frac{2x}{2x^2+x}\rightarrow2.$$
$$f(x^2,x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^4+2x^2+x^2}\rightarrow\frac{2}{3},$$ which says that the limit does not exist.